# how to set the path to where aapt add command adds the file

Tags: path, addition, aapt

I'm using aapt tool to remove some files from different folders of my apk. This works fine.

But when I want to add files to the apk, the aapt tool add command doesn't let me specify the path to where I want the file to be added, therefore I can add files only to the root folder of the apk. 
This is strange because I don't think that developers would never want to add files to a subfolder of the apk (res folder for example). Is this possible with aapt or any other method? Cause removing files from any folder works fine, and adding file works only for the root folder of the apk. Can't use it for any other folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The aapt tool retains the directory structure specified in the add command, if you want to add something to an existing folder in an apk you simply must have a similar folder on your system and must specify each file to add fully listing the directory. Example

```
$ aapt list test.apk
res/drawable-hdpi/pic1.png
res/drawable-hdpi/pic2.png
AndroidManifest.xml

$ aapt remove test.apk res/drawable-hdpi/pic1.png
$ aapt add test.apk res/drawable-hdpi/pic1.png
```

The pic1.png that will is added resides in a folder in the current working directory of the terminal res/drawable-hdpi/ , hope this answered your question

Comment: I already wrote my own tool to replace aapt for what I needed. But thanks for the ideea. Good to know in the future. I would vote up for your answer but I don't have the necessary reputation yet.

Answer (score 8):

There is actually a bug in `aapt` that will make this randomly impossible. The way it is supposed to work is as the other answer claims: paths are kept, unless you pass `-k`. Let's see how this is implemented:

The flag that controls whether the path is ignored is `mJunkPath`:

```
bool        mJunkPath;
```

This variable is in a class called `Bundle`, and is controlled by two accessors:

```
bool getJunkPath(void) const { return mJunkPath; }
void setJunkPath(bool val) { mJunkPath = val; }
```

If the user specified `-k` at the command line, it is set to `true`:

```
case 'k':
    bundle.setJunkPath(true);
    break;
```

And, when the data is being added to the file, it is checked:

```
if (bundle->getJunkPath()) {
    String8 storageName = String8(fileName).getPathLeaf();
    printf(" '%s' as '%s'...\n", fileName, storageName.string());
    result = zip->add(fileName, storageName.string(),
                      bundle->getCompressionMethod(), NULL);
} else {
    printf(" '%s'...\n", fileName);
    result = zip->add(fileName, bundle->getCompressionMethod(), NULL);
}
```

Unfortunately, the one instance of `Bundle` used by the application is allocated in `main` on the stack, and there is no initialization of `mJunkPath` in the constructor, so the value of the variable is random; without a way to explicitly set it to `false`, on my system I (seemingly deterministically) am unable to add files at specified paths.

However, you can also just use `zip`, as an APK is simply a Zip file, and the `zip` tool works fine.

(For the record, I have not submitted the trivial fix for this as a patch to Android yet, if someone else wants to the world would likely be a better place. My experience with the Android code submission process was having to put up with an incredibly complex submission mechanism that in the end took six months for someone to get back to me, in some cases with minor modifications that could have just been made on their end were their submission process not so horribly complex. Given that there is a really easy workaround to this problem, I do not consider it important enough to bother with all of that again.)

Comment: thanks for the info Jay. I finally wrote a simple java tool that adds file to the apk (considering it [as you said] a zip), using ZipInputStream and ZipEntry.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "zip tool" you refer to some tool named "zip" and not to the archive type, cause unzipping an apk and adding some files it's pretty simple, but compressing it back and also building the newly added files it's not possible with "zip" ;) I used apktool for that.

Comment: I am confused what you mean by "building the newly added files"; in my case I am adding things like `classes.dex` (built using `dx`) to an existing APK by way of `zip my.apk classes.dex` without issue.

Comment: For example, if i want to change the icon of my app just by replacing the icon image in the res/drawable folder it wouldn't work. I'm guessing that the new resource needs an id in the auto-generated R class which is generated when building happens. So, I used apktool to decode the apk, then added my new image and then I built the apk back, again using apktool.

Comment: Hi Jay I have a question for u. I need to remove "classes.dex" from existing .apk files in data/app folder. Then I need to repackage it as normal .apk. I am to do it by using zipfile in java. But what happens it when I flash it on the emulator some dummy icon comes in place of the original icon. But res folder and manifest.xml everything is there. Can u give some inputs??

Comment: @JayFreeman-saurik-: Would be nice to have a link to the bug report associated with this aapt issue.

Comment: @Gili: Please read the final paragraph of my answer (the one in parentheses) again.

Comment: @CodeGuru: I am sorry; I know nothing of the "dummy icon" and I do not use the emulator. I would recommend asking a question on Stack Overflow, assuming you have not do so already.